# Program that calculates sum and average using functions

Tags: c++

I am doing a C++ question where I need to generate a random number, then this random number is how many integers the program will prompt the user to enter.

Then I need to use two separate functions: 1 to calculate and return the sum, and another to calculate and return the average.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int calculateSum(int, int);
int calculateAvg(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int average = 0;
    int x;
    int y;
    int n = 0;

    srand(time(0));
    y = rand() % 10;

    for (x = 1; x <= y; x++) {
        cout << "Enter integer " << x << ": ";
        cin >> n;
    }
    cout << "Sum: " << calculateSum(n, sum) << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << calculateAvg(average, sum, y) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int calculateSum(int n, int sum)
{
    sum = sum + n;
    return sum;
}

int calculateAvg(int average, int sum, int y)
{
    average = sum / y;
    return average;
}
```

The problem with the code is whenever I run it, it only takes the last integer to calculate the sum (for example, if the last integer entered was 5, the sum of all the integers would be 5 which is incorrect because it ignores the previous integers from the user), and the average is always 0, any help to fix these issues would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you could have used `rand()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `int n` only has room for a single integer, so your for-loop just overwrites `n` with each integer you input. Naturally, the last integer you enter will be the only one saved by the time you leave the for-loop.

You need to call `calculateSum()` in the for-loop, so that it increments `sum` every iteration of the loop. So instead of:

```
for (x = 1; x <= y; x++) {
    cout << "Enter integer " << x << ": ";
    cin >> n;
}
cout << "Sum: " << calculateSum(n, sum) << endl;
```

You would set it up like this:

```
for (x = 1; x <= y; x++) {
    cout << "Enter integer " << x << ": ";
    cin >> n;
    sum = calculateSum(n, sum); // increment sum every iteration
}
cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
```

---

And somewhat unrelated to this particular issue, your `calculateSum()` and `calculateAvg()` functions don't actually update the `sum` and `average` variables you've defined in `main()`; they only return the results of those functions.

To pass `sum` and `average` in by reference (what you're trying to accomplish here), you need to change your function signatures from:

```
int calculateSum(int n, int sum);
int calculateAvg(int average, int sum, int y);
```

To:

```
void calculateSum(int n, int &sum);
void calculateAvg(int &average, int sum, int y);
```

(I've also changed the return type from `int` to `void` since you don't need to return `sum` nor `average` - you'd have already modified them in their respective functions)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `n` every time in your loop, but only update `sum` at the end. Update `sum` every time.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you should use arrays, not typical integer
instead of your current `n`

```
int array[10];
for(int i=0; i <=y; i++)
{
cin >>n;
array[i] = n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the entered values in a vector and then use std::accumulate.

See the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate